# Intersection of multiple lists in elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

How to get the intersection of multiple lists using elisp?  I'm a elisp newbie but I'm imagining there is some builtin function or a nicer solution using reduce.  I cobbled this together, but it seems overly complicated.

```
;; get the intersection of these lists
;; result should be (3 4 5)
(setq test '((0 1 2 3 4 5) (2 3 4 5 6) (3 4 5 6 7)))

(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-remove-if-not
 (lambda (x) (cl-every
         (lambda (y) (> (length (memq x y) ) 0 ) )
         (cdr test) ) )
 (car test) )
;; ( 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `cl-intersection` that takes only two operands:

```
(cl-intersection '(0 1 2 3 4 5) '(2 3 4 5 6))
```

You can use it do define your own intersection:

```
(defun my-intersection(l)
    (cond ((null l) nil)
          ((null (cdr l)) (car l))
          (t (cl-intersection (car l) (my-intersection (cdr l))))))

(my-intersection '((0 1 2 3 4 5) (2 3 4 5 6) (3 4 5 6 7)))
```

**Updated**

Thanks to the @Tobias comment below, you could have in the new function the same keyword parameters of `cl-intersection`, that is (`:test :test-not :key`) and propagate them to all the calls to it inside the recursion.

Here is the extended version:

```
(defun my-intersection(l &rest cl-keys)
    (cond ((null l) nil)
          ((null (cdr l)) (car l))
          (t (apply 'cl-intersection (car l) (apply 'my-intersection (cdr l) cl-keys) cl-keys))))
```

Comment: Proposal: Add an argument `&rest rest` and replace the `cl-intersection` by `(apply 'cl-intersection (car l) (apply 'my-intersection (cdr l) rest) rest)`. In this way you can use the optional arguments like `:test` and so on. Maybe as an extended version.

Comment: What if I would like to do the same thing except with a vector?

Answer (score 4):

Install [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) third-party list manipulation library (follow [instructions](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#installation) to install it). Then you need:

```
(-reduce '-intersection '((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6))) ; => (3 4)
```

If you need a function that accepts variable number of lists, instead of a single list of lists, wrap it in a function using [`&rest`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/A-Sample-Function-Description.html#A-Sample-Function-Description) keyword, like that:

```
(defun -intersection* (&rest list-of-lists)
  (-reduce '-intersection list-of-lists))
;; (-intersection* '(1 2 3 4) '(2 3 4 5) '(3 4 5 6)) ; => (3 4)
```

If it's the first time you use [`-reduce`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-fn-list), it's a “fold” function: it takes a binary function, a list of elements, and reduces them to a final result one list element at a time. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109467/596361) explains the concept behind the fold.