# Define elisp function, takes 2 lists and returns number of times atom in list 1 occurs in list 2

Tags: elisp

How would i define a function that takes in 2 lists(l1 l2) and returns the number of times an atom in list 1 occurs in list 2.

Comment: This question could help you get most of the way there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050033/elegant-way-to-count-items

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to iterate over the second list, counting how many of the things you come across appear in the first. The `member` function lets you do that test, so you might end up with one of these two options:

```
;; A version with explicit recursion down the list
;;
;; This will blow its stack if list is too long.
(defun count-known-atoms (known list)
  "Return how many of the elements of `list' are atoms and appear
  in `known'."
  (if (null list)
      0
    (let ((hd (car list)))
      (+ (if (and (atom hd) (member hd known)) 1 0)
         (count-known-atoms known (cdr list))))))

;; A version using local variables and side effects. Less pretty, if you're a
;; fan of functional programming, but probably more efficient.
(defun count-known-atoms-1 (known list)
  "Return how many of the elements of `list' are atoms and appear
  in `known'."
  (let ((count 0))
    (dolist (x list count)
      (when (and (atom x) (member x known))
        (setq count (1+ count))))))

;; (count-known-atoms   '(1 2) '(0 1 2 3 4 5))    => 2
;; (count-known-atoms-1 '(1 2) '(0 1 '(2) 3 4 5)) => 1
```

If ELisp had a `sum` function to sum across a list or some sort of `fold`, another option would be to map across the second list to get zeros and ones and then squash them down afterwards. I don't think it does, though, so I'd suggest `count-known-atoms-1`.