# How does currying work?

Tags: haskell, currying

I'm very new to Haskell and FP in general. I've read many of the writings that describe what currying is, but I haven't found an explanation to how it actually works.

Here is a function: `(+) :: a -> (a -> a)`
If I do `(+) 4 7`, the function takes `4` and returns a function that takes `7` and returns `11`.  But what happens to `4` ?  What does that first function do with `4`? What does `(a -> a)` do with `7`?

Things get more confusing when I think about a more complicated function:

```
max' :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
max' m n | m > n = m
         | otherwise = n
```

what does `(Int -> Int)` compare its parameter to?  It only takes one parameter, but it needs two to do `m > n`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352855/in-functional-programming-what-is-currying -- a good resource for you!

Comment: @progo: that's a good link, but I don't think it's what the questioner is asking.  This is clearly asking for how currying is implemented, not what it is.

Comment: you just construct a new expression why you define new anything.
any expression won't be calculated except you try to show or force it.
I suggest you read a term about lambda calculus in wikipedia

Answer (score 25):

### Understanding higher-order functions

Haskell, as a functional language, supports higher-order functions (HOFs). In mathematics HOFs are called [functionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_%28mathematics%29), but you don't need any mathematics to understand them. In usual imperative programming, like in Java, functions can accept values, like integers and strings, do something with them, and return back a value of some other type.

But what if functions themselves were no different from values, and you could accept a function as an argument or return it from another function? `f a b c = a + b - c` is a boring function, it sums `a` and `b` and then substracts `c`. But the function could be more interesting, if we could *generalize* it, what if we'd want sometimes to sum `a` and `b`, but sometimes multiply? Or divide by `c` instead of subtracting?

Remember, `(+)` is just a function of 2 numbers that returns a number, there's nothing special about it, so any function of 2 numbers that returns a number could be in place of it. Writing `g a b c = a * b - c`, `h a b c = a + b / c` and so on just doesn't cut it for us, we need a general solution, we are programmers after all! Here how it is done in Haskell:

```
let f g h a b c = a `g` b `h` c in f (*) (/) 2 3 4 -- returns 1.5
```

And you can return functions too. Below we create a function that accepts a function and an argument and returns another function, which accepts a parameter and returns a result.

```
let g f n = (\m -> m `f` n); f = g (+) 2 in f 10 -- returns 12
```

A `` (\m -> m `f` n) `` construct is an [anonymous function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function) of 1 argument `m` that applies `f` to that `m` and `n`. Basically, when we call `g (+) 2` we create a function of one argument, that just adds 2 to whatever it receives. So `let f = g (+) 2 in f 10` equals 12 and `let f = g (*) 5 in f 5` equals 25.

<sup>(See also [my explanation of HOFs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27657332/596361) using Scheme as an example.)</sup>

### Understanding currying

[Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is a technique that transforms a function of several arguments to a function of 1 argument that returns a function of 1 argument that returns a function of 1 argument... until it returns a value. It's easier than it sounds, for example we have a function of 2 arguments, like `(+)`.

Now imagine that you could give only 1 argument to it, and it would return a function? You could use this function later to add this 1<sup>st</sup> argument, now encased in this new function, to something else. E.g.:

```
f n = (\m -> n - m)
g = f 10
g 8 -- would return 2
g 4 -- would return 6
```

Guess what, Haskell curries all functions by default. Technically speaking, there are no functions of multiple arguments in Haskell, only functions of one argument, some of which may return new functions of one argument.

It's evident from the types. Write `:t (++)` in interpreter, where `(++)` is a function that concatenates 2 strings together, it will return `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`. The type is not `[a],[a] -> [a]`, but `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`, meaning that `(++)` accepts one list and returns a function of type `[a] -> [a]`. This new function can accept yet another list, and it will finally return a new list of type `[a]`.

That's why function application syntax in Haskell has no parentheses and commas, compare Haskell's `f a b c` with Python's or Java's `f(a, b, c)`. It's not some weird aesthetic decision, in Haskell function application goes from left to right, so `f a b c` is actually `(((f a) b) c)`, which makes complete sense, once you know that `f` is curried by default.

In types, however, the association is from right to left, so `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` is equivalent to `[a] -> ([a] -> [a])`. They are the same thing in Haskell, Haskell treats them exactly the same. Which makes sense, because when you apply only one argument, you get back a function of type `[a] -> [a]`.

On the other hand, check the type of [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:map): `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, it receives a function as its first argument, and that's why it has parentheses.

To really hammer down the concept of currying, try to find the types of the following expressions in the interpreter:

```
(+)
(+) 2
(+) 2 3
map
map (\x -> head x)
map (\x -> head x) ["conscience", "do", "cost"]
map head
map head ["conscience", "do", "cost"]
```

### Partial application and sections

Now that you understand HOFs and currying, Haskell gives you some syntax to make code shorter. When you call a function with 1 or multiple arguments to get back a function that still accepts arguments, it's called [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application).

You understand already that instead of creating anonymous functions you can just partially apply a function, so instead of writing `(\x -> replicate 3 x)` you can just write `(replicate 3)`. But what if you want to have a divide `(/)` operator instead of `replicate`? For infix functions Haskell allows you to partially apply it using either of arguments.

This is called [sections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator): `(2/)` is equivalent to `(\x -> 2 / x)` and `(/2)` is equivalent to `(\x -> x / 2)`. With backticks you can take a section of any binary function: `` (2`elem`) `` is equivalent to `` (\xs -> 2 `elem` xs) ``.

But remember, any function is curried by default in Haskell and therefore always accepts one argument, so sections can be actually used with any function: let `(+^)` be some weird function that sums 4 arguments, then `let (+^) a b c d = a + b + c in (2+^) 3 4 5` returns 14.

### Compositions

Other handy tools to write concise and flexible code are [composition](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition) and [application operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/$). Composition operator `(.)` chains functions together. Application operator `($)` just applies function on the left side to the argument on the right side, so `f $ x` is equivalent to `f x`. However `($)` has the lowest precedence of all operators, so we can use it to get rid of parentheses: `f (g x y)` is equivalent to `f $ g x y`.

It is also helpful when we need to apply multiple functions to the same argument: `map ($2) [(2+), (10-), (20/)]` would yield `[4,8,10]`. `(f . g . h) (x + y + z)`, `f (g (h (x + y + z)))`, `f $ g $ h $ x + y + z` and `f . g . h $ x + y + z` are equivalent, but `(.)` and `($)` are different things, so read [Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940382/596361) and [parts from Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application) to understand the difference.

Comment: Great explanation. Question: In the implementation, for say a function with 3 or more arguments where I first pass 2, does it "reduce" calling the function with one argument for each argument (which in this case would still return a function expecting 1 argument)? Also, if I call function with full argument count does it do any "shortcut" or does it go through the same thing as I noted above?

Comment: A function of 3 arguments in Haskell is a function of type a -> b -> c -> d, which is equivalent to a -> b -> (c -> d), which is equivalent to a -> (b -> (c -> d)). So yes, currying is exactly the same no matter how many arguments your function requires to be fully evaluated. Whether GHC rewrites curried functions to multi-variate functions in the intermediate code — this I don't know. Was that your question? I can update my answer to explain these ideas more clearly.

Comment: To my first question: I'm deducing  that GHC is doing some kind of reduce until it exhausts the number of arguments given (each reduction returning a x->y function and applying that to the next, if any, argument). The second question is not as important, for my understanding, as the first. The veil of mystery has been lifted and I thank you sir.

Answer (score 15):

You can think of it like that the function stores the argument and returns a new function that just demands the other argument(s). The new function already knows the first argument, as it is stored together with the function. This is handled internally by the compiler. If you want to know how this works exactly, you may be interested in [this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/HaskellExecution/FunctionCalls#Genericapply) although it may be a bit complicated if you are new to Haskell.

If a function call is fully saturated (so all arguments are passed at the same time), most compilers use an ordinary calling scheme, like in C.

Comment: +1.  `map' 4` is a function with one argument and it has type `Int -> Int`

Answer (score 13):

Does this help?

```
max' = \m -> \n -> if (m > n)
                       then m
                       else n
```

Written as lambdas. max' is a value of a lambda that itself returns a lambda given some m, which returns the value.

Hence max' 4 is

```
max' 4 = \n -> if (4 > n)
                   then 4
                   else n
```

Answer (score 4):

Something that may help is to think about how you could implement curry as a higher order function if Haskell didn't have built in support for it.  Here is a Haskell implementation that works for a function on two arguments.

```
curry :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> (b -> c)
curry f a = \b -> f a b
```

Now you can pass `curry` a function on two arguments and the first argument and it will return a function on one argument (this is an example of a closure.)

In ghci:

```
Prelude> let curry f a = \b -> f a b
Prelude> let g = curry (+) 5
Prelude> g 10
15
Prelude> g 15
20
Prelude>
```

Fortunately we don't have to do this in Haskell (you do in Lisp if you want currying) because support is built into the language.

Comment: I would say it makes more sense to transform an uncurried function, which uses a tuple, to a curried function which doesn't, for the example.

Comment: Maybe, I thought an example without tuples would be very similar to what Haskell allows and intermediate data structures might confuse things.

Answer (score 3):

If you come from C-like languages, their syntax might help you to understand it. For example in PHP the add function could be implemented as such:

```
function add($a) {
    return function($b) use($a) {
         return $a + $b;
    };
}
```

Comment: With the only difference, that this performs much better in Haskell.

Comment: No doubt about that. I just felt that explicit currying (and explicit closures) might help understanding the concepts a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Haskell is based on Lambda calculus. Internally what happens is that everything gets converted into a function. So your compiler evaluates `(+)` as follows

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(+) x y = \x -> (\y -> x + y)
```

That is, `(+) :: a -> a -> a` is essentially the same as `(+) :: a -> (a -> a)`. Hope this helps.