# Haskell: Sending parameters to multiple functions

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner to Haskell. This is an example from my lectures, where we define our function **permu** which should produce all permutations of a list.

```
permu :: [a] -> [[a]]
permu [] = [[]]
permu (x:xs) = concatMap (insertAll x) $ permu xs
insertAll :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
insertAll = undefined
```

I'll leave insertAll as undefined for now, as it is not the part that I need help with.
My problem is this: `concatMap` has the type `Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]` and should thus take two parameters. However, `insertAll` should also take two parameters.

As far as I can tell `concatMap` takes `insertAll x` as first parameter and `permu xs` as the second. This all is good. But it looks to me like `insertAll` only takes the argument `x`.

Is it possible that both `concatMap` and `insertAll` takes `permu xs` as their second parameter, or am I missing something??
Thank you!

Comment: `insertAll x` is [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6652234/5923139): it's equivallent to `\arg -> insertAll x arg`.

Comment: Oh, now I see! I've been trying to google this problem for a while, and getting a name for it helped a lot!

Comment: @JonatanMatiasVaara Sometimes it's helpful to understand that in Haskell all functions always take exactly one argument. What we call "N-ary" functions (N>1) actually are *unary* functions whose return value is just another (N-1)-ary function. When we call `f arg1 arg2` we actually call `f` with `arg1`, get the resulting function, and call that with `arg2`. Indeed, `f arg1 arg2` is equivalent to `(f arg1) arg2` and to `let resultFun = f arg1 in resultFun arg2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it looks to me like insert all only takes the argument x.

As the comment mentioned, Haskell functions are curried by default. This makes *partial application* of them easy - simply providing less arguments than the function "takes" leaves you with a partially applied function that will take the rest.

In your case, partially applying `insertAll` on `x` leaves us with a `[a] -> [[a]]` function, which makes the signature compatible with the first argument of `concatMap`. The second argument to `insertAll` is effectively provided within `concatMap`.